# Sharing named volumes in Docker Compose gives me 'device or resource busy' in one of my containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cmake

Here is the problem I have :

My docker-compose file looks as below :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  development:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: build.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/development:z # Source directory
      - buildarea:/buildarea:z # Build directory

  service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: run.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/development:z
      - buildarea:/buildarea:z # Build Directory
    depends_on:
      - development

volumes:
  buildarea:
```

This is a C++ CMake project. I want to build my code within my container and use as `build-directory` (for my cmake-build) `/buildarea` within my container and mount that to named volume, so it can be shared by the `service` container.

When I try via Docker CLI I get :

```bash
docker-compose build development
docker-compose run --rm development
[root@bc8c4d32d1a6 development]# ....make command...
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/buildarea'
make: *** [Makefile:5: docker] Error 1
```

When I use VSCode Remote Containers :

```
1. Open the folder in a container
2. run the same build command
it works fine
```

Why is that? Both of them are using the `development` container, but it looks like it doesn't work the same from CLI & VSCode.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Is it possible to do the compilation step in a Dockerfile, and have only a single container with no volumes mounted?  That might be a simpler setup and a better-defined workflow.

Comment: @DavidMaze I can do compilation step in docker yes, but I don't get why for the same container, when running via CLI it doesn't work, and via VSCode Docker extension it works.